# Populating a ListView with items from an array in Java

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have 4 fields on a custom row layout for a listview.  I have 4 fields in my array that I want to map to those 4 fields on the listview:

1. cat_ID_PK
2. cat_name
3. cat_amount
4. is_recurring

I have no idea how to correctly do that.  Here's what I have so far:

```
private void loadListView(Expenses[] mExpenseArray) {

//This code will write the "name" variable correctly to the logcat, so I know I'm 
getting the right values in my array.

    String name = mExpenseArray[0].getCatName();
    Log.v("log_tag", name);

    ArrayAdapter<Expenses> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Expenses>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, R.id.catName, mExpenseArray);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This code only populates `R.id.catName`, but when it populates it, it looks like this:  `mypackage@8ed455` (or something similar).  None of the other fields are populated at all, which I'm guessing has to do with the 3rd parameter in my ArrayAdapter being `R.id.catName`.  However, if I take this parameter out I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Here is the code for my custom row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/catName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom ="10dip"
    android:text="@string/catName"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/catAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingBottom ="10dip"
    android:text="$45.00"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/catType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/catName"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/catName"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/catType"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="catID"
    android:id="@+id/catID"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/catType"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/catType"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/catType"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I correctly map my 4 array fields to my ListView?

Comment: You must use a custom adapter

Comment: try to use custom adapter.

Comment: `Expenses` supposed to be a data model so you have to use a custom adapter in order to get the value from the model.

Comment: Can you recommend a good tutorial on that?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503876/repeat-linearlayout-element-containing-other-ui-elements-and-fill-it-with-data/26504445#26504445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a custom adapter like this and then assign the values to the text views

pass array like this to adapter

```
UserList disadpt = new UserList(HomePage.this, mEmployeeList);
    userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
```

then in adapter do this ..

```
public class UserList extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Employee> items;

    public UserList(Context c, ArrayList<Employee> items) 
    {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.items = items;
    }

        public int getCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup arg2) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);
        mHolder = new Holder();

        //mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
        mHolder.txt_fName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_fName);
        mHolder.txt_lName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_lName);
        mHolder.txt_userName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_userName);

        child.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }

    Employee employee = this.items.get(pos);

    ArrayList<String> employeeInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    employeeInfo.add(employee.employeeId);
    employeeInfo.add(employee.firstName);
    employeeInfo.add(employee.lastName);

    mHolder.Details.setTag(employeeInfo);

    mHolder.txt_fName.setText(employee.firstName + " " + employee.lastName);    
    mHolder.txt_userName.setText(employee.emailId);

    return child;
}

public class Holder 
{
    //TextView txt_id;
    TextView txt_fName;
    TextView txt_lName;
    TextView txt_userName;
    Button Details;
}
}
```

hope this helps ...

Comment: I'd be passing an array to the custom adapter. In your example you're passing in each individual element.  Would I have to pass in each individual element?  If I can pass in my array, how do I handle that once its passed to the custom adapter?  New to java, so this is all harder than it should be.

Comment: @hyphen I just edited my answer you can pass an array to the custom adapter try the edited answer and then tell me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Create String type of array Adapter and use-

```
adapter.add(mExpenseArray[0].getCatName());
```

by using any loop.